# How can I handle collisions of multiple blocks as if they were a single entity?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm creating a 2D platform game using Corona SDK and I'm stuck with collisions.

Basically there is a character that runs over this ground made of blocks. This is because sometimes there can be holes in the ground.
The game is an endless one, so as the character moves forward new blocks (and holes) are dynamically added - and also removed if they goes off screen.

[image: ground blocks]

It works nicely but this approach works against the collision system, let me explain how.
Now that I have the ground in place I want the character to jump but only if it is touching the ground, to avoid jumping while in air.
Whenever a collision is detected between `character` and `ground` an event is fired - two times. The first time when the character is entering a ground block and the second time when the character leaves it. So when the character lands on the ground a `isGround` Boolean is set to true. And when - after a jump - it leaves it the flag is set to false. The problem is that every time it exits a block to enter another - walking along the ground without jumping - the flag get updated. This makes the jump based on the isGround flag less reliable. Sometimes it happens that you can't jump because `isGround` == `false` though the character is on the ground.

**Ground block creation snippet**

```lua
-- init() method set the sprite of the ground block and physic to that sprite
function GroundBlock:init()
    self.sprite = display.newImageRect(self.path, self.width, self.height)

    self.sprite.x = self.x
    self.sprite.y = self.y

    physics.addBody(self.sprite, 'static', {
        density = 0,
        friction = 0,
        bounce = 0,
        box = {
            halfWidth = self.width / 2,
            halfHeight = self.height / 2,
            y = 16,
            x = 0
        }
    })

    local collisionObj = {
        name = 'ground'
    }

    self._collision = collisionObj
    self.sprite._collision = collisionObj

    self.isShow = true
end
```

**Ground placing GroundBlocks snippet**

```lua
-- init() method initialize the ground with a fixed number of blocks
function Ground:init()
    self.offsetX = 0
    while self.offsetX < self.camera.borderRight * 2 do
        self._createBlock(1)
    end
    self.lastCameraPos = self.camera.borderRight
end

-- update() is called once per frame
function Ground:update()

    if (self.camera.borderRight - self.lastCameraPos > self._blockWidth) then
        local rand = math.ceil(math.random() * 10) % 2

        if self._skippedBlock >= 2 or rand == 0 then
            self._createBlock(1)
            self._skippedBlock = 0
        else
            self._createBlock(0)
            self._skippedBlock = self._skippedBlock + 1
        end

        self.lastCameraPos = self.camera.borderRight
    end

    for i, block in ipairs(self.blocks) do
        if block.sprite.x < self.camera.borderLeft - block.width then
            table.remove(self.blocks, i)
            self.camera:remove(block.sprite)
            block:delete()
        end
    end
end
```

**Collision detection snippet**

```lua
function Character:collision(event)
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        if event.other._collision.name == "ground"  then
            self.isGround = true
        end

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

        if event.other._collision.name == "ground" then
            self.isGround = false
            print('nope')
        end

    end
end
```

A solution would be to make a ground as a single imgRect but how to make holes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code and prevent this issue from ever occurring by tracking if the character can jump instead of tracking if the character is on the ground.

For instance,

```
function jump( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if canJump then
            canJump = false
            -- your code that makes the player jump
        end
    end
end
```

You probably use touches to determine whether the player character jumps, right? This way, you'll trigger the jump when the touch starts as long as the character has not already jumped.

You could then reset this value in your collision function by editing it slightly:

```
function Character:collision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if event.other._collision.name == "ground" then
            canJump = true
        end
    end
end
```

This way, the character's ability to jump is determined by whether or not the player has pressed jump already and if the character has hit the ground since the last jump.

This kind of approach also gives you the ability to pivot towards implementing mechanics like double jump. If instead of using a boolean `canJump` variable you chose to use a number variable, e.g. `jumpsLeft`, you could reduce the number of jumps left every time the character jumps and only let the character jump if `jumpsLeft` is larger than 0. Then you'd simply reset the value back to 1 (or whatever you'd want upon hitting the ground).